# Wicket multi-tab ajax & page serialization

Tags: ajax, serialization, wicket

I have a nasty issue with `Wicket` and `Ajax` on `VMWare Horizon`. What users see is that ajax-links do not work as expected. To be exact: they work, but seem to act on a older version of the page. For example, when I have a counter, it does seems to handle an ajax-update, but the value is never increased. The value is stored in a `Model` so I figured it has something to do with page serialization.

I went on to do a more simpler experiment: on the Wicket-Exmaples (see: http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/on-change-ajax-behavior) there is a input box. If you press `enter`, the value is submitted to the page. This works fine in one browser tab.

However, if I open two tabs (by copy-pasting the url in a new tab, let's call them **A** and **B**). I submit a value in tab **A** using enter. I refresh the tab **B** and get the value what is submitted in tab **A**.

The only way this can happen seems to be that they read each-other's serialized pages.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

ps. I use `Wicket` version 6.19.0, the wicket examples seems to run 6.x. 
ps2. I noticed this behaviour in Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To prevent this you should make sure that there are no two or more tabs opened on the same page (i.e. with the same page id).
You can use https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/2f3b357703df3fe5c49580b3c46d4fd231208474/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxNewWindowNotifyingBehavior.java to be notified when this happens. Just do `setResponsePage(getPage().getClass())` to start on a fresh instance.

Comment: Thanks @martin-g, this looks useful. I was wondering if it was possible to create a new `WebSession` for that tab, so that everything else 'just works'. What do you think?

Comment: The session is encoded as a cookie "JSESSIONID". The browser sends it automatically. So all tabs and windows are the same user at the server side. You can encode it in the url and explicitly remove it for this link but this is manual work you have to do...

Answer (score 0):

That is because two tabs work in one session.

The tabs are not considered (because they are not known to the server) for deciding which session a request is for.

If you would do the same with two browsers instead of two tabs it would work fine.

Comment: Thanks @Glenner003 for the extra explanation. However, I would really like to prevent this :)

Comment: How exactly do you open the second tab? Are you passing the version parameters over as well? Wicket will then display the page at that same state (the version parameter is used so back button support can be achieved)
If you're opening the second tab without any version parameters you should have 2 seperate pages.